# Accessing arrays of strings from child processes that have been created before the fork in C linux

Tags: c, linux, process, multidimensional-array

i have three process, one father and two sons,since the sons get by heritage everything that was created before i forked how do i access the arrays of strings that i have created before from the son or the father?
 i want to access the two arrays of strings that i have created before i forked with the name of string_hashes and hashes from the sons and the father?
 Thanks for the help...

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>




#define PIPE_NAME   "np_workmaster"
#define max_chars_string 1000
#define n_childs 2

typedef struct
{
  int a;
  int b;
} numbers;



pid_t childs[n_childs];

void read_lines(char * filename, char (*pointer)[max_chars_string],int init_read,int n_lines);
void get_strings_hash(char (*pointer_strings)[max_chars_string],char (*pointer_hashes)[max_chars_string],int total_lines);

void worker(){ // meter as funcoes de ler passwords no filho
    char * ant = "";
    char hash_char;

    printf("[%d] I'm the son!\n", getpid());
    printf("[%d] My parent is: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    exit(0);
}

void pparent(){// sera o ultimo processo a terminar mostrando as passwords ja recebidas do dispatcher que recebe dos outros filhos
    printf("[%d] I'm the father!\n", getpid());
    //dispatcher() // criar funcao dispatcher que envia dados ao outro processo...

  int fd;
  if ((fd=open(PIPE_NAME, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
  {
    perror("Cannot open pipe for writing: ");
    exit(0);
  }

  // Do some work  
  while (1) {
       // here i  want to access arrays strings_hashes and hashes from the father and sons

    printf("[CLIENT] Sending (%d,%d) for adding\n", n.a, n.b);
    write(fd, &n, sizeof(numbers));
    sleep(2);
  }

  return 0;

}






int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *filename;
    int status;//status do processos filho
    int resources[2];// numero de linhas que cada processo tem de ler
    //char * chave_iniciadora = "";
    int n_lines; //numero de linhas do ficheiro
    int i = 0;



    filename = (char*)malloc(strlen(argv[1])*sizeof(char)+1);

    if(argc !=3){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s [text_file] [cores]",argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    strcpy(filename,argv[1]);
    n_lines = count_lines(filename); // contem o numero de linhas
    //definicao arrays
    char strings_hashes[n_lines][max_chars_string];//aray de string com as strings lidas do ficheiro
    char hashes[n_lines][max_chars_string]; // array de strings com as hashes
    char * pointer_string = &strings_hashes[0][0]; // ponteiro para o inicio do array das strings lidas do ficheiro
    char * pointer_hashes = &hashes[0][0];//ponteiro para o inicio do array das hashes

    //funcoes
    share_resources(atoi(argv[2]),n_lines,resources);
    read_lines(filename,strings_hashes,0,n_lines); // le as strings do ficheiro e passa para o array
    get_strings_hash(strings_hashes,hashes,n_lines);
     //
    for(i = 0; i<n_lines;i++){
        printf("%s",strings_hashes[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i<n_lines;i++){
        printf("%s",hashes[i]);
    }

    //   
  for(i = 0; i <atoi(argv[2]);i++){
        childs[i] = fork();
        if(childs[i] == -1){
           perror("Failed to fork");
           return 1;
       }
       if (childs[i] == 0)
       {
          worker();
       }
       else
       {
          pparent();
          wait(&status);
          if (!status)
            printf("\nOK\n");
          else 
            printf("\nSomething is wrong...\n");
    }
   }
  return 0;
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



//funcionar
void get_strings_hash(char (*pointer_strings)[max_chars_string],char (*pointer_hashes)[max_chars_string],int total_lines)//vai ao array de strings e corta a parte de hash e mete num array
{
    int i = 0;
    char *strings;
    char *hash;

    for(i = 0;i<total_lines;i++){
            strings = (char*)malloc(strlen(pointer_strings)*sizeof(char)+1);
            strcpy(strings,*pointer_strings);
            hash = (char*)malloc(strlen(pointer_strings)*sizeof(char)+1);
            find_hash(strings,hash);
            strcpy(*pointer_hashes,hash);
        pointer_hashes++;
        pointer_strings++;
    }

}



//funcionar
int count_lines(char * filename){ 
    FILE *fp;
    char str[max_chars_string];
    int i =0;

    if((fp = fopen("ficheiro_leitura.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
      printf("Cannot open file.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        while(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp)) {
           i++;
      }

  }
  fclose(fp);
  return i;
}
//funcionar
void read_lines(char * filename, char (*pointer)[max_chars_string],int init_read,int n_lines){ 
    FILE *fp;
    char str[max_chars_string];
    int i =0;


    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r"))==NULL) {
      printf("Cannot open file.\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    if(init_read>0 && init_read<=n_lines){
     for(i = 0;i<init_read;i++){
         fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
       for(i = init_read;i<n_lines;i++){
           fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
           strcpy(*pointer, str); //copia para a posicao actula do ponteiro
           pointer++;
       }
     }
    }
    if(init_read<=n_lines && init_read==0){
       for(i = init_read;i<n_lines;i++){
            fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
           strcpy(*pointer, str); //copia para a posicao actula do ponteiro
           pointer++;
       }
     }


  fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special.  Currently you have them defined in `main()`.  Either define them globally or pass them to your `worker()` (i.e. child) function.

Keep in mind they are now 3 separate copies of same thing so if one process changes them those changes will not be reflected in the other processes.  If that is your intent then it probably easiest to put them in shared memory and protect them with a mutex.